# Extract data frame columns every 8 columns

Tags: r

Attempting to extract a data frame column every 8 columns.

I am trying to use seq, and subset the column [,col.number]

```
new.df <- data.frame(seq(from=(df[,9]),to=length(df),by=8))
```

heres a dummy data frame:

```
# Random data frame for illustration (100 columns wide)
df <- data.frame(replicate(100,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
```

anyway to subset a column, every 8 columns along with seq?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(100, sample(0:1, 1000, rep = TRUE)))
new.df <- df[, seq(from = 9, to = ncol(df), by=8)]
```

Comment: Thx - I was pretty close!!